# when i upgrade php version 5.4 after codeigniter site give 500 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some trouble when I upgrade PHP version 5.4 on my site. My site is built with CodeIgniter framework. It's working fine in previous version. When I check error log I see this error

```
error: cannot stat directory: (root_directory/project name/index.php/home)

Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
```

Comment: What PHP version were you using before?

Comment: previous php version is 5.3

Answer (score 0):

> cannot stat directory

It is linux error, not the PHP. In most common case after upgrading PHP you have changed user and/or group running php binary and new one simply does not have permissions to code directory.

So the answer will be - change user/group thats's running php.

Comment: ok but i have one issue if i load site url so welcom.php conroller worked but when i change url http://www.example.com/index.php/conroller_name/home  give a 500 error